# Why were the Atreides guarded so weakly?

Tags: dune

From them moment Shaddam IV ordered him to Arrakis, Duke Leto knew that it was a trap. He was even aware that there was a traitor in their ranks. Nevertheless when the Duke was attacked by

> Dr. Yueh

he didn't have any bodyguards with him. Moreover, the shield generator - which one would assume their most important line of defense - was so weakly guarded that not only could a complete stanger like

> Esmar Tuek

get near it but it was also possible for a single person to eliminate all it's guards.

Given this, why didn't the Atreides guard themselves better?

Comment: I'm reading the books in german so I can't provide any quotes here. Feel free to add some if appropriate

Comment: The Atreides family were (they thought) surrounded by loyal followers. There's no need for a bodyguard if you trust everyone near you

Comment: @Valorum but they knew this wasn't the case. Thufir Hawat even distrusted Lady Jessica

Comment: He mistrusted her motives. I don't think he mistrusted her as a security threat until he was given a (mistaken) reason to think so

Comment: Here's a hypothesis I've toyed with: Frank Herbert was not that good a writer.

Comment: Plus Yueh was, IIRC, a doctor conditioned by the Suk School and supposedly incapable of betraying their patients or taking a human life (presumably out of medical context). Nobody had ever broken the Suk conditioning before, so this was a unique threat that could never be expected.

Comment: The Atreides were thought to have the most intelligent and strategical sound  (Thufir), skilled and fierce fighters (Duncan and Gurney) and loyal top-end support and were well on the way to win the hearts and minds of the Fremen plus knew to expect some form of attack, they just didn't think it would come from within their own camp.

Comment: @Seamusthedog It was also much bigger than expected.  As it was happening Thufir observes how it much it must have cost to pull off such an attack and how long it would take to regain the cost.  He notes they never expected such a scale and even if they had, they would not have been able to prepare for such an attack especially in the time they had (or at all without either the Fremen or increasing the size of the small elite portion of their they had begun to train).

Comment: @suchiuomizu something like 60 years of OTE the Harkonnens needed to recoup the cost?

Comment: Yeah, the Atreides were also thrown off and doomed by the Emperor secretly sending his Sardaukar to join the attack. They were prepared as much as they could be against the Harkonnen and thought they had a decent chance. It was the Emperor that screwed them.

Comment: “Nothing wins more loyalty for a leader than an air of bravura," the Duke said. "I, therefore, cultivate an air of bravura.”

Comment: I believe they were as well-guarded as they could have been.